# NodeJS ler json time series linha a linha

Tags: json, node.js, nodemon

Acesso uma API, que faz a previsão de valores futuros, a API me retorna o JSON abaixo:

```
{ series:
   { '2020-02-13': '62.5000',
     '2020-02-14': '64.5800',
     '2020-02-15': '30.7700',
     '2020-02-16': '60.8700',
     '2020-02-17': '58.5400',
     '2020-02-18': '68.3800',
     '2020-02-19': '83.6900',
     '2020-02-20': '76.1900',
     '2020-02-21': '55.2000',
     '2020-02-22': '75.1700',
     '2020-02-23': '46.4900',
     '2020-02-24': '43.8000',
     '2020-02-25': '88.6500',
     '2020-02-26': '79.1400',
     '2020-02-27': '53.3900',
     '2020-02-28': '64.0600',
     '2020-02-29': '74.4500',
     '2020-03-01': '73.6800',
     '2020-03-02': '77.9100',
     '2020-03-03': '67.8600',
     '2020-03-04': '66.0400',
     '2020-03-05': '38.9500',
     '2020-03-06': '51.4300',
     '2020-03-07': '63.0400',
     '2020-03-08': '58.3300',
     '2020-03-09': '55.4500',
     '2020-03-10': '59.7400',
     '2020-03-11': '63.7700',
     '2020-03-12': '76.7300',
     '2020-03-13': '89.8000',
     '2020-03-14': '69.2300',
     '2020-03-15': '69.7400',
     '2020-03-16': '31.2500',
     '2020-03-17': '59.8100',
     '2020-03-18': '92.8600',
     '2020-03-19': '48.4200' } }
```

Preciso ler esses valores linha a linha pois vou adiciona-los em um banco de dados, exemplo do que vou fazer em cada leitura de linha:

```
insert into previsao (dia, valor) VALUES (json.dia, json.valor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode converter os dados obtidos da API para JSON, assim:

`const data = JSON.parse(response);`

Logo após obter os dados e transformá-los em objeto, você pode colocá-los em uma matriz, assim:

`const entries = Object.entries(data.series);`

Que vai retornar a seguinte matriz (somente os 3 primeiros vetores):

```
[
    ["2020-02-13", "62.5000"],
    ["2020-02-14", "64.5800"],
    ["2020-02-15", "30.7700"]
]
```

Então você pode acessar eles assim:

```
for (const entrie of entries) {
    console.log(entrie); // ["2020-02-13", "62.5000"] na primeira execução, e assim vai...

    console.log(entrie[0], entrie[1]); // 2020-02-13 62.5000
}
```

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Ao tentar passar o retorno para json 'const dataJson = JSON.parse(data);', recebo o erro: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request.request.post [as _callback] (F:\Desenvolvimento Node\liberacao-direta\liberacao_direta_v2\index.js:265:31)

Comment: Matheus, veja se o seu data já não é um objeto, caso contrário, use o `console.log(data)` para ver o que está retornando... ele tem que estar em um formato de objeto (`{ chave: "valor" }`)

Comment: Lucas obrigado, ficou assim const entries = Object.entries(data.series);
        for (const entrie of entries) {...., funcionou

Comment: Boa, Matheus! :D